# Why is this /fill ... replace command not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I attempt to execute the command `/fill ~50 ~1 ~50 ~-50 ~-1 ~-50 minecraft:grass_block replace minecraft:jungle_wood`, I receive the a message saying "No blocks were filled."

The command syntax itself is correct as I don't get an error message and none of the text is red when typing it.

I am running on Minecraft 1.13.2.

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Do you want to replace all Jungle Wood Planks with Grass or the other way round? What is your expected result or goal?

Comment: Are there even blocks like that in the area? If not, then not replacing anything is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least four possible causes for this issue.

**Firstly, let's dissect the syntax of the `/fill` command, though, with focus on the `replace` feature.**

`/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 block_type_1 replace block_type_2`

`/fill` - the command. This tells the game **what feature it should execute**.

`x1, y1, z1` - the coordinates of the first corner. This tells the game **where it should start filling**.
`x2, y2, z2` - the coordinates of the second corner. This tells the game **where it should stop filling**.
It will fill every block with the coordinates of **any x between x1 and x2**, **any y between y1 and y2** and **any z between z1 and z2**.

`block_type_1` - this tells the game **what block you want to fill this are with**. **This is the block that will be placed on the fitting coordinates after passing through the additional, optional arguments**.

`replace` - the additional optional argument. This tells the game that **it should only replace blocks of a certain type**. This argument has no effect without including the next one.

`block_type_2` - this tells the game **what block type you want to be replaced**. **This is the block that will be replaced by `block_type_1` if it has fitting coordinates.**

**Now, let's take your command as an example and say what it does by running it through the list I've compiled.**

`/fill ~50 ~1 ~50 ~-50 ~-1 ~-50 minecraft:grass_block replace minecraft:jungle_wood`

`x1` = `~50`
`y1` = `~1`
`z1` = `~50`

`x2` = `~-50`
`y2` = `~-1`
`z2` = `~-50`

`block_type_1` = `minecraft:grass_block`
`block_type_2` = `minecraft:jungle_wood`

This tells the game that it should fill **all blocks that are within 50 blocks on each horizontal axis and 1 block on the vertical of the player**, with **blocks of type `minecraft:grass_block`**, but **only if the block was of type `minecraft:jungle_wood` before this command was executed**.

In short, it means it replaces all jungle wood within the cuboid with grass blocks.

Now that we know exactly what the command does when executed, the next step is to troubleshoot.

Here are the possible reasons why the command doesn't work as expected.

## 1. There might be no blocks of this type in that area

Check if there really is jungle wood within the cuboid to be replaced with grass blocks. Try:

1. Checking your command. Are you sure you want to replace jungle wood with grass blocks, and not the other way around?
2. Using the [testforblocks command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/testforblocks) to see if there are blocks of that type in the area.

## 2. The command might be used by a plugin, preventing it from working

If you are playing on a multiplayer server with plugins installed, one of the plugins might include a `/fill` command that functions similarly to the Minecraft version, however produces a different result.

If this is the case, try executing the command with the prefix `minecraft:` instead. (`/minecraft:fill ...`)

## 3. Your installation of Minecraft might be corrupted

Despite this being extremely unlikely, if no other solutions work, it is worth trying to **reinstall Minecraft**, as during the installation, an error might have occured.

## 4. Your installation of Java might be outdated or corrupted

This option is still highly unlikely, however if the problem persists, try updating or reinstalling Java on your device. **Stay away from development/unstable builds as they might have some mistakes/typos in them.**

Only download Java from the [official website](https://www.java.com/en/download/).

Comment: Thank you for this good help, I will use the test for blocks command, as I don't have any plugins. perhaps it is corrupted :/

Comment: @ElyianaFilms Perhaps you wrote the command the other way around; this turns jungle wood into grass blocks,

Comment: That's not how the `/testforblocks` command works